# How to call enumerator's next in yield block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

I have a bulk update process which updates a **Product**'s (*has_many*) **Subscription** and is called in several places, so I refactor it into a service.

In each place where calls this process still has its own special pre-process: like adding counter, etc.
and some subscriptions :update can be *skipped* if it will be destroyed.
So I send block to it:

```rb
# subscriptions_params is an array containing permitted parameters from controller
module SavingService
  def self.call!(product, subscriptions_params)
    subscriptions_params.each do |params|
      subscription = product.subscriptions.find(params[:id])

      next if block_given && !yield(subscription, params)

      subscription.update!(params)
    end

    product.update_something!
  end
end

# It can work well
SavingService.call!(product, subscriptions_params)

# I can add some special process in the block
SavingService.call!(product, subscriptions_params) do |subscription, params|
  if params[:checked]
    subscription.counter += 1
    true
  else
    subscription.destroy!
    false
  end
end
```

However, I need to explicitly return **true** or **false** to do **"next"**, it will be hard to maintain after... like 6 months.
Every developer will be confused that why it needs to return **true**, **false** explicitly.
Is there any way I can call next from the block? or don't need to use the block?

I know I can solve this problem by applying *Template Pattern*: make an abstract class containing the process and inherit it to overwrite each private method:

```rb
class SavingService
  def call!
    pre_process
    process
    post_process
  end

  private

  def pre_process; end
  def process; end
  def post_process; end
end
```

But the different parts of each place calling the process are very small, just 1~3 lines.
I don't want to create so many classes for such tiny differences, so I choosed to use block first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [`catch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#catch-method) and [`throw`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#throw-method) to make the skipping more explicit:

```
module SavingService
  def self.call!(product, subscriptions_params)
    subscriptions_params.each do |params|
      catch(:skip) do
        subscription = product.subscriptions.find(params[:id])
        yield(subscription, params) if block_given?
        subscription.update!(params)
      end
    end
    product.update_something!
  end
end

SavingService.call!(product, subscriptions_params) do |subscription, params|
  if params[:checked]
    subscription.counter += 1
  else
    subscription.destroy!
    throw(:skip)
  end
end
```

Comment: never seen this before!

Comment: @kevinluo201 you rarely need it. Rails uses `throw :abort` for [halting execution](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#halting-execution) of callback chains.

Answer (score 2):

`next` is control flow, so no, you cannot `next` from inside the yield.

Using `block_given?` is the only way to do it with this callback structure (without nonlinear control flow like `raise` or `throw`), and as you've mentioned, it works a bit weird b/c abstraction doesn't quite fit.

I think it would be more straightforward to "to things in-place" instead of injecting a block, like this:

```rb
to_increment, to_destroy = subscriptions_params.partition { |p| p[:checked] }

product.subscriptions.where(id: to_increment.map { _1[:id] })
  .each { |sub| sub.counter += 1 }
  .then { |subs| Subscription.update_all(subs) } # something like this, I forget exact syntax

product.subscriptions.where(id: to_destroy.map { _1[:id] }).destroy_all!
```

The reason for this is because there's not much shared logic or "work" to really extract -- it's just doing some action(s) multiple times.

Perhaps what you're looking for is to build those actions into `Subscription` as methods? like this:

```rb
class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  def increment!
    self.counter += 1
  end
end

product.subscriptions.where(id: to_increment).each(&:increment!).each(&:update!)
```

Or perhaps all you need is an `update_subs!` like:

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  def update_subs!(sub_ids)
    subs = subscriptions.where(id: ids).each { |sub| yield sub }
    subs.each(&:update!)
  end
end

# one line each, can't get much more straightforward than this
product.update_subs!(to_increment) { |sub| sub.counter += 1 }
product.subscriptions.where(id: to_destroy).each(&:destroy!)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I chose catch and throw one because that exactly what I want.
but your answer inspires me a lot! Especially for this phrase: *The reason for this is because there's not much shared logic or "work" to really extract -- it's just doing some action(s) multiple times.*